# jQuery - mousemove crashing my firefox

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery('#test .track, :not(.btn)').mousemove(function(e){   
        var el = e.target;
        jQuery(el).mouseover(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
            jQuery(this).click(function(){
                jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
                show_data(this); // a small function for showing this class, css
            })
        }).mouseout(function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('highlight');
        });

});
```

This code is crashing my firefox when click continuously.
I am using this code to highlight current DOM element under mouse.

Comment: maybe you can replace jQuery with $. It's essentially the same thing but make your codes look nicer.

Comment: Type error : $ is not a function

Comment: Using $  is not a big issue, you've 2 event handlers within mousemove.  Maybe that the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was your event registration model, you where registering `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers to the specified elements whenever mouse is moved over them, causing may be thousands of event handlers to be registered to each of them. This might cause the browser to suspend the js execution.

Try

```
jQuery('#test .track, :not(.btn)').mouseover(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
}).mouseout(function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('highlight');
}).click(function(){
    jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
    show_data(this); // a small function for showing this class, css
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wG7Aw/)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be attaching a new event handler every single "tick" of the mouse moving on the target elements. This can extremely rapidly lead to hundreds, thousands of event handlers. This is bad news in [Vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/); in jQuery it's a nuke.

You are then adding a new `click` event handler for every time the mouse moves over a target element, setting another nuke.

Then you click a few times... and BOOM!

Comment: You should almost never assign an event handler inside another event handler. Look at your code, think about what you're trying to do... because honestly I can't tell. I *think* you should take your `.highlight` class in the CSS and replace it with `#test .track:hover, :not(.btn):hover` to apply the styles, and then just delete all that script except the `click` handler, and put your `#test .track, :not(.btn)` selector into the `jQuery` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get element based on mouse coordinates.

```
var element = $(selector)
function handler(e){     
   var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
   var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
   $(elementMouseIsOver).addClass('yourClass');
}
element.on('click', handler);
element.on('mouseover', handler);
```

If you want to get elements based on hover

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
```

If you want to apply styles on hover and remove on mouse out

```
$(ele).hover(function(){
   // Hover Event
   $(this).addClass('xyz');
}, function(){
   // Hover done Event
   $(this).removeClass('xyz');
});
```